# Access session variables from a class extension

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to access session variables from a class extension?

I have this variable set in session:

```
var offset = 3;
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("clienttimeoffset", offset);
```

And in a DateTime extension I need to access it:

```
public static DateTime? ToClientTime(this DateTime? value)
 {
    if (value == null)
         return null;

    var offset = get it here .....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't access it inside the extension. Pass it as a parameter to the extension method:

```
public static DateTime? ToClientTime(this DateTime? value, int offset)
 {
    if (value == null)
         return null;

        ....
}
```